# Set last day of month in date

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

how can I set a month date to appear with last day of month. Currently I have

```
 2008-01-01 for January
```

but I want it

```
 2008-01-31.
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use replace of datetime module

```
import datetime
datetime.datetime.strptime('2008-01-01','%Y-%d-%m').replace(day=31)
```